# Python not checking csv against input

Tags: python

I'm creating a project during my spare time which is a user-based quiz with score-keeping and high score tallies. Currently i'm stuck with stage 1 of the creation which is the login section. I'm using CSVs for this as I have found them easier to edit than other methods.

The problem is that it only checks the first row of the file and nothing else. This can cause issues when it comes to people added after the first row, as it checks the first row, sees they don't match and throws the "Incorrect" error below.

I've used print() statements to try and see if there's any issues with inputs or python checking the csv file, however everything seems perfectly fine, it's responding with the full csv in the correct format, so it should work.

```
def login():
        print("\n")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print("Create an account")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        uname = input("Enter name: ")
        pword = input("Enter a password: ")
        print("----------------------------------------")
        print("Please wait...")
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        UD = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'users.csv'), 'r')
        for line in UD:
            user = line.split(",")
            print("input for uname is: "+uname)
            print("input for pword is: "+pword)
            print(user[0])
            print(user[1])
            if user[0] == uname and user[1] == pword:
                print("\n")
                print("-----------------------------------------")
                print("Login successful!")
                print("-----------------------------------------")
                UD.close()
            else:
                print("\n")
                print("----------------ERROR!-----------------")
                print("Incorrect username / password!\n")
            break
```

The CSV file currently contains only these entries:

```
person1 password1
person2 password2
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is gladly appreciated.

Edit: Output of running the current code:

```
Enter name: person1
Enter a password: password1
----------------------------------------
Please wait...
-----------------------------------------


----------------ERROR!-----------------
Incorrect username / password!
```

Comment: If your CSV file looks like that, then it's probably because you're not splitting the lines correctly. In the line `user = line.split(",")` you're splitting by a comma. Try it with `user = line.split()`

Comment: returned with the error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What is the error you get when you run your code as is?

Comment: it prints `print("----------------ERROR!-----------------") print("Incorrect username / password!\n")`

Comment: Can you add the whole output, including all the results of the `print` functions you have, to the question?

Comment: added the whole output

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

The data fields are separated by spaces rather than commas, so that you want to write

```
user = line.split(' ')
```

or even, because by default `split()` uses sequences of blanks as separators

```
user = line.split()
```

I'd like to mention that you can *unpack* the results of a split and use more significant names for the variables

```
user, passwd = line.split()
```

Next, you say that there is no match between user input and stored data, but this happens because `input()` strips new lines from its results, while iteration on a file object returns lines that do contain the newlines, so that you have to `strip()` your data items before using them.  This can be achieved simply,

```
user, passwd = [item.strip() for item in line.split()]
```

Eventually, I have to mention that your login procedure is not correct, because if your user provided username and password as `"person2"` and `"password2"` it will check against the first line, will refuse the login and will break out of the loop, and I bet this is not what you want...

I'd write

```
for user, passwd in (item.strip() for item in open(...)):
    if user==uname and passwd==pword:
        print('OK')
        success = 1
        break
else:
    print('No login')
    success = 0

if not success: sys.exit()
play_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Well first,your csv is not really *coma separated* so fix that
2.It is failing all the time because of the trailing white space in each line
3.This is just a note, you would be better off using the `with` statement as it is the pythonic way
4.You could fix the whitespace issue with `.strip()`

Here is a working solution to your problem

```
import os
def login():
    print("\n")
    print("-----------------------------------------")
    print("Create an account")
    print("-----------------------------------------")
    uname = input("Enter name: ")
    pword = input("Enter a password: ")
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("Please wait...")
    print("-----------------------------------------")
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.csv'), 'r') as f:
        files = f.readlines()

    for f in files:
        # print('Entry: ',f)
        user,pwd = f.split(",")
        print(user,'\t',pwd)
        print("input for uname is: "+uname)
        print("input for pword is: "+pword)

        if user == uname and pwd[:-1] == pword:
            print("\n")
            print("-----------------------------------------")
            print("Login successful!")
            print("-----------------------------------------")
            break
    else:
        print("\n")
        print("----------------ERROR!-----------------")
        print("Incorrect username / password!\n")
    print(len(uname),len(pword))#this is the length of your inputs
    print(len(user),len(pwd))#This is the length of your compare values, note length of password

login()
```

## The else in the for loop executes if no matches were found, learn something new